# Call .click event from a dropdown onchange

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I am using jtable to display cd albums where the user can filter and search by cd name and cd category. The code to reload the table after a change is made uses .click event when a button is pressed. I was wanting to use the button to search on cd Name and use a onchange event to filter records by category rather than press a button each time. Is is possible to trigger the .click using the onchange?

Javascript:

```
//Re-load records when user click 'load records' button. 
        $('#LoadRecordsButton').click(function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $('#AlbumTableContainer').jtable('load', { 
                CDTitle: $('#name').val(), 
                catID: $('#catID').val()
            }); 
        }); 

        //Load all records when page is first shown 
        $('#LoadRecordsButton').click();
```

html:

```
<form> 
        CD Name: <input type="text" name="cdName" id="cdName" /> 
        Category:  
        <select id="catID" name="catID" onchange="WhatDoIPutHERE"> 
            <?php
                echo "<option>Select an option</option>";
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($category)){
                    $id = $row["catID"];
                    $cat = $row["catDesc"];
                    echo "<option value=\"$id\">$cat</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select> 
        <button type="submit" id="LoadRecordsButton">Load records</button> 
    </form>
```

Comment: That's what happens when people start with jQuery without perfecting JS

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi Well thanks for your input however I dont get to pick and choose what modules college give me! The assingment is for web design however they want us to incorporate some jQuery in parts but have not taught us any javascript. Love how people just assume on this forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#cdName, #catID').on('change', function() {
   $('#LoadRecordsButton').click(); 
});
```

This will register the change event for both the textbox and dropdown to fire the click event.

However it would probably be better to have the `load` functionality in a seperate function and call this function on each of the events :

```
function loadjTable() {        
   $('#AlbumTableContainer').jtable('load', { 
       CDTitle: $('#name').val(), 
       catID: $('#catID').val()
   });
}

$('#LoadRecordsButton').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   loadjTable();
});
$('#cdName, #catID').on('change', function() {
   loadjTable();
});
```

This would probably make your code more easy to follow and understand.

Comment: I could kiss you! Sat at work trying to juggle work and my college and getting very stressed. Got this working now. Got an error about $('#cdName, #catID').on('change', function() not being a function so looked on the internet and found a similar example from W3Schools and changed it to this: $("#catID").change(function(){loadjTable() }); Thanks so much!